# Repeated measures linear mixed effects model

Tags: r, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I am working with trees that were fertilized in a full factorial design (N x P x K) in plots that are replicated four times. I currently have a mixed effects model with this structure:

```
> library("nlme")
> model <- lme(growth ~ P*N*K, data=Lars_noNA, random=~1|rep/block/plot4040)
> summary(model)
```

Where `rep` = replicate, `block` is part of the blocking layout, and `plot4040` is a plot that received a nutrient treatment. Now I want to growth by individuals measured multiple times over 15 year and but I don't know if this is the way to handle the error associated with the repeated measures.

```
>library (nlme)
>model <- lme (AGBnew ~ P*N*K+year, data=mydata_sorted1, 
               random=~1|rep/block/plot4040/individual/year) 
>summary(model)
```

Comment: If you are only asking how to use R, this question would be off-topic for CV. It might be a good question for the r-help-listserv. Can you clarify?

Comment: well, while part of it is about using r, the fundamental question is about how you properly structure the model for nested effects and repeated measurements for handling the error correctly. I apologize if this is not quite along the lines of this forum. I should also say, that the r model works, but I am not sure that is doing what I want it to statistically.